# three js does not render gltf

Tags: angular, three.js

i am working on adding a gltf model to my angular application. however this is not working, according to the inspector in chrome the div is rendered but i don't see a model. i am also not sure what the error is because i have specified a `min-height` and `min-width`, which i found out by researching this can be a source of error.

any suggestions where the error could be?

home.page.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit  {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.25,
    20
     );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

  controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();


  ngOnInit(): void {

    var elm = document.getElementById('app');
    console.log(elm);
    
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    // scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.2);
  
    
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(300, 350);
    
    elm!.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
 
    this.camera.position.set(-1.8, 0.6, 2.7);

    this.controls.listenToKeyEvents(window); // optional

    this.controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;
  
    this.controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
  
    this.controls.minDistance = 1;
    this.controls.maxDistance = 5;
  
    this.controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
  
    // world
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    const fileURL =
      'assets/scene.gltf';
    loader.load(
      fileURL,
      (gltf) => {
        this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
      },
      undefined,
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );


    const dirLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    dirLight1.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    this.scene.add(dirLight1);
  
    const dirLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    dirLight2.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    this.scene.add(dirLight2);
  
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    this.scene.add(ambientLight);
  
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize);
    
  }

  onWindowResize() {
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate()); // Aufruf der animate()-Methode in einer Schleife
    this.controls.update(); // nur notwendig, wenn controls.enableDamping = true oder controls.autoRotate = true ist
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  
}
```

home.page.scss:

```
#container {
  text-align: center;

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#container strong {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

#container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;

  color: #8c8c8c;

  margin: 0;
}

#container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


#app{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

home.page.html:

```
  <div id="app"></div>
```